# Select range copy paste run macro clear loops till blank column,

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to copy column A of karai1.xlsx to column A of wipbuj2.xlsx and then run the following macro to copy information to a Word document. Then I want to repeat this by copying column B of karai1.xlsx to column A of wipbuj2.xlsx and run the copy-to Word macro. Then column C of karai1.xlsx, etc, until I reach a blank column. Below is my attempt at copying the first column.

What i need is:  copy column from workbook karai1.xlsx paste in workbook wipbuj2.xlsx in  A(1st column) run macro/ code following

```
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add


wdApp.Visible = True

Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("A1:g39").Select
Selection.Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
wd.SaveAs
wd.Close
wdApp.Quit
```

then copy from column 2 from workbook karai1.xlsx paste in wippuj2.xlsx A column run macro run this loop till blank column in sheet karai1.xlsx .

Please help.

this is the code i was working

```
enter code here 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\DO\Desktop\WIP buj 2.xlsx"
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
Sheets("calculations").Select
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\do\Desktop\desktop\karai data\KARAI 1.xlsx"

Range("A1:A177").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("WIP buj 2.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("calculations").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add


wdApp.Visible = True

Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("A1:g39").Select
Selection.Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
wd.SaveAs
wd.Close
wdApp.Quit
```

Comment: maybe do a list of actions as I'm a little not sure about what you want so    1. copy column A from wksht 1                                                                     2, paste in to wksht 2 column 1                                                                     3, run macro A   etc.

Comment: What is the Word application doing in your code. You don't mention it in your task description but it is prominent in the code which you claim to have been working.

Comment: @Variatus - I **THINK** the question can be read as "I want to copy column A of karai1.xlsx to column A of wipbuj2.xlsx and then run the following macro to copy information to a Word document.  Then I want to repeat this by copying column B of karai1.xlsx to column A of wipbuj2.xlsx and run the copy-toWord macro.  Then column C of karai1.xlsx, etc, until I reach a blank column.  Below is my attempt at copying the first column.".  But I'm not confident enough of my interpretation to edit the question to say that.

Comment: @YowE3K, thank you for reframing, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by adding a simple loop across each column, stopping when the cell in row 1 is empty, you should be able to achieve what you are after.

Refactored code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    Dim wsCpy As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long

    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    wdApp.Visible = True

    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\DO\Desktop\WIP buj 2.xlsx")
    Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("calculations")
    Set wsCpy = wbDst.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\do\Desktop\desktop\karai data\KARAI 1.xlsx")
    Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet ' Would be better to define this explicitly using the sheet name

    c = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wsSrc.Cells(1, c).Value)
        wsSrc.Cells(1, c).Resize(177, 1).Copy wsDst.Range("A1")

        'Copy to Word
        'Create new document
        Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
        'Copy Excel data
        wsCpy.Range("A1:g39").Copy  'Avoid Excel's "Select" whenever possible!
        'Paste in Word
        wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
        'Save and close
        wd.SaveAs
        wd.Close

        'Next column
        c = c + 1
    Loop

    wdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, it helped me a lot ,  Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("calculations") & wsCpy = wbDst.Worksheets("Sheet5") **was showing error**, changed to  Set **wsDst = sheets("calculations")& wsCpy = sheets("Sheet5")** and working fine.

Comment: @AKumar Those corrections seem strange to me - changing `Worksheets` to `Sheets` should only fix a problem if "calculations" and "sheet5" were `Charts` rather than `Worksheets` (in which case you wouldn't be able to use a `Range` with them), and getting rid of the `wbDst.` qualifying which workbook they belonged to (and using the default `ActiveWorkbook` instead) shouldn't have done anything because `wbDst` would have been the `ActiveWorkbook` following the `Open` statement.